# with template constructor,template argument deduction/substitution failed,why?

Tags: c++, templates

such are the codes:

```
template<typename T>
struct ST{
ST();
ST(T t){}
};
template<typename T>
void fun(ST<T> t, T a){
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  ST<int> t=2;
   fun(2,2);
}
```

compile with g++ 4.8.2
errinfo:

> no matches for fun(int,int)
>
> Candidate is:
>
> template void fun(ST, T)
>
> template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>
> mismatched types ‘ST’ and ‘int’

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
template<class T>struct identity{typedef T type;};
template<class T>void fun(typename identity<S<T>>::type s, T t)
```

this will block the compiler from trying to do argument type deduction on the first argument.

`template` type matching is pattern matching.  Few conversions are done, as in the general case it cannot be solved (is there a `T` such that `X<T>` can be converted from type `Z` is Turing-complete up to arbitrary limits of `template` compilers: recursion depth etc).

In C++11 you can do:

```
template<class T>struct identity{typedef T type;};
template<class T>suing identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;
template<class T>void fun(identity_t<S<T>> s, T t)
```

which I find cleaner (moves boilerplate away from other code).

Answer (score 2):

Implicit type conversions are not used for deducing template arguments, you have to manually specify the type in this case `fun<int>(2,2);`

Comment: and the corresponding C++ standard?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Template_argument_deduction (The relevant part of the standard is § 14.8.2).

Answer (score 1):

Your function signature is `void fun(ST<T> t, T a)`, but you call the function with `fun(int, int)`. Just like your error says, these do not match. If the type deduction for `fun` was `int`, the signature would look like: `fun(ST<int> t, int a)`, you would call it with `fun(t, 2)`.

Comment: but there is a constructor ,to convert int to ST<int>